# Why not convert all .properties files to UTF-8?

Tags: java, character-encoding, properties-file

I work on a java project where labels are externalized and translated into `.properties` files.

Resources in java are read using ISO-8859-1 encoding and thus the `.properties` files are also stored in ISO-8859-1 encoding.
The current files are messed up, sometimes using escapes `\u00E4` and sometimes using the actual letter `öäü`.
Also I have russian translations which look like this:

```
code.adr=\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441
```

This could be stored in clear text using UTF-8.

Now the question is, why not use UTF-8?
Why does Java use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 per default, backwards compability?
Are there any known downsides, converting all `.properties` files to UTF-8?

Comment: That spec was written WAY before UTF-8 became the generally accepted default encoding. And since it was specified like this it has to stay like this. That being said, you *can* load properties files with an encoding of your choice, but expect some confusion to be had there (I vaguely remember that some Spring components actually use UTF-8 by default).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using ResourceBundle, switching to **ListResourceBundle** might be feasible: that is pure java (arrays).
2. Alternatively you might want to **generate the *.properties** from say an XML translation memory xliff or whatever. That has the advantage of being able to add comments; create a glossary and such.