# How to make eclipse read bundle properties in UTF-8?

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization, eclipse-rcp, properties-file

Externalizing the strings of an eclipse RCP bundle, e.g. from extension points, results in a `bundle.properties` or `plugin.properties`. Translating those properties into Russian results in `bundle_ru.properties`.

Is there a way I can tell my Eclipse RCP application to read those Resources as **UTF-8** instead of **ISO-8859-1**?

Comment: Can't you just change encoding under file properties? Also, you can specify locale, when loading a bundle.

Comment: @AlexK. The classes Eclipse uses to read localization properties files don't know about the Eclipse file encoding property setting so unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported. The code that reads the bundle properties file ends up using the `PropertyResourceBundle` class which always assumes ISO-8859-1

Comment: okey, too bad... I was hoping to switch to UTF-8 for all properties, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769205/why-not-convert-all-properties-files-to-utf-8)... but only being able to handle some properties, I will just leave everything as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it for Eclipse RCPs, but for other Java properties that had to be translated I ran the Russian translations through the [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) converter to generate an ASCII properties file with escaped Cyrillic characters. I like to keep a copy of the UTF-8 properties file, though, because it makes it easier to implement corrections if some user reports an incorrect translation.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the problem lays on the eclipse side. It does not help to convert the properties to UTF-8 if eclipse reads them in ISO-8859-1. That will cause problems.

Comment: Well, you would have to keep ISO-8859-1 files in Eclipse, but you could convert them to UTF-8, get them translated as UTF-8, convert the translations back to ASCII using the converter I mentioned above, and put the converted translated properties files back into Eclipse. Two questions remain: can Eclipse display \uXXXX characters correctly (I would assume so), and is it worth the effort?